# Composition of Linear Rotations and Reflections

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if $T_{1}$ is a rotation of $R^{2}$ about O, and $T_{2}$ a reflection in a line through O, then $T_{1}$$\circ$$T_{2}$ and $T_{2}$$\circ$$T_{1}$ are both reflections in a line through O.

I'd prefer a hint than the answer, because I'm not sure how to begin. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I realized, previous to the edit, the question might have looked like I was multiplying. I have remedied it; it is composition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 different types of (non-trivial) isometries of the plane. They are rotations, reflections, translations and glide translations.

Hint: The non-trivial isometries of the plane are classified according to the existence of fixed points, and if they preserve orientation.

Hint: Both $T_1 (T_2)$ and $T_2 (T_1)$ **have/don't have** fixed points, and **preserve/don't preserve** orientation, hence they must be $\underline{ \quad \quad \quad} $.

Comment: @arthur Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: one way would be to represent rotations and reflections by canonical matrix representatives, and then compute the matrix products.

Answer (score 0):

You can assume without loss of generality that $O$ is the origin point. Then write the rotation matrix as $(\cos[\theta],-\sin[\theta]),(\sin[\theta],\cos[\theta])$. Try to write the reflection matrix out as well and see how the multiplication goes. If you are stuck, Artin's book may be a good reference.