# Dihedral groups and reflections

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, dihedral-groups

> Let $\rho\in D_{10} $ be a rotational symmetry in $\frac{2\pi}{5}$ radians non-clockwise,and let $\epsilon\in D_{10}$ be a reflection symmetry (related to the X-axis).Prove that every $\epsilon\rho^i\in D_{10}$ is a reflection symmetry.

For $i=5$,I know that $\rho^5=e=\epsilon^2$,so $\epsilon\rho^5=\epsilon$.But I don't know what can I say about $1\le i \le 4$...
Any ideas/hints?

Comment: How do you define "reflection symmetry"?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398660/composition-of-linear-rotations-and-reflections By the way, what you call a "symmetry" is a transformation in the plane.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_symmetry <<That way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\rho$ and $\epsilon$ in your question can be related by $\rho^{i} \epsilon \rho^{i} = \epsilon$. You can convince yourself about this by drawing a figure.

Therefore, $(\epsilon \rho^i)^2 = \epsilon (\rho^i \epsilon) \rho^i = \epsilon (\epsilon \rho^{-i}) \rho^i = e$.

So $\epsilon \rho^i$ is a symmetry of pentagon which squares to the identity, it must be a reflection then.

Comment: Is there any way to prove that $\rho^i\epsilon\rho^i=\epsilon$?

Comment: @TakaTiki These are linear transformations in the plane, so they can be written using $2\times2$ matrices. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334567/find-the-standard-matrix-for-the-composition-of-reflection-and-rotation) for an idea of what it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

All the rotations are of the form $\rho^j$ so if $\epsilon \rho^i$ were a rotation we would have $\epsilon \rho^i = \rho^j$, whence $\epsilon= \rho^{j-i}$. But $\epsilon$ isn't a rotation, so this is a contradiction. Hence $\epsilon \rho^i$ is a reflection.